# create workflow in this activities

Tags: workflow

I want to create workflow that has steps/sequence like :

Create the sharepoint site in the MOSS2007
Create the 3 User Groups 
•   Content  Providers
•   Content  Approvers
•   Content  Publishers 
Create 4 Document Libraries Namely as 
1.  Current
2.  Pending Approval
3.  Approved
4.  Published
Now Add the world document to the Current document library.
Steps:
a)  As  user upload the document , the document shud remain checked  out to begin with. When the user checks in the document, the document will move to Pending Approval  in check in mode.
b)  Now Approver will log in , and will check out the document  from the Pending Approval Doc Lib.
c)  As Approver check s in that document , then that will moved to the Approved Document  Library
d)  Further,  Publisher will check out the document from the Approved Document  Library, and will say check in . then document will moved to Published  Document  Library

How to do this programmtically?